# recursive common table expression with a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, with-statement

This is what Im trying to do:

```
Create view vDetailsCommunications as
WITH Tickets AS
(
    SELECT  CallLog.CallID
          , CallLog.RecvdDate
          , Detail.ReqEffDate
          , Asgnmnt.DateAcknow
          , Asgnmnt.DateResolv
          , Asgnmnt.Assignee
          , Asgnmnt.GroupName
          , CallLog.CallType
          , Detail.ActionReq
          , Detail.action_type
          , (SELECT [Days] FROM NonWorkingDays(Asgnmnt.DateAcknow, Asgnmnt.DateResolv) AS NonWorkingDays_1) AS [Working Days]
          , DATEDIFF(day, Asgnmnt.DateAcknow, Asgnmnt.DateResolv) AS [Days]
          , (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Asgnmnt.CallID ORDER BY Asgnmnt.DateAcknow)) AS [Row Number]
    FROM    CallLog 
    INNER JOIN  Detail ON CallLog.CallID = Detail.CallID 
    INNER JOIN  Asgnmnt ON CallLog.CallID = Asgnmnt.CallID
    WHERE (CallLog.CallType = 'ID Request-PAF')
      AND (Detail.ActionReq = 'Hiring Action')
      AND (DATEDIFF (DAY, Asgnmnt.DateAcknow, Asgnmnt.DateResolv) BETWEEN 0 AND 99)
      AND (Asgnmnt.GroupName IN ('ID Admin', 'Systems Admin'))
      AND (Detail.action_type IN ('Applicant Hire', 'Re-Hire'))
)
SELECT *
FROM Tickets
WHERE [Row Number] = 1
```

Comment: Please add a question or error, as well as revise your post to use Code formatting.

Comment: Now that we can read the query...is there a question here?

Comment: Dont see any recursion here, neither a question   :S

Comment: It will not allow me to create a view.

Comment: CTEs are like temp tables and table variables, not allowed in a view.

Comment: @HLGEM you actually can use CTEs in a view. I think the Answer may be the right one, a schema will need to be given. The function will also need to be scalar rather than a table function, i believe.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define a schema in this function: NonWorkingDays.

ex:

```
SELECT [Days] FROM dbo.NonWorkingDays(Asgnmnt.DateAcknow, Asgnmnt.DateResolv)
```

Comment: if the answer has helped set the answer as correct. thank you